# Multiple enum value in swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, enums

I want to create an enum value like

```
view.autoresizingMask = [UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin, UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight]
```

I can not figure out to to design the `enum` to accept multiple variable.

I want to design the below.

```
enum ActivityType: Int {
    case Event = 1
    case CommentOnEvent = 2
    case CommentOnComment = 3
}
var activityType = [CommentOnEvent, CommentOnComment]

var activityType = Event
```

Comment: show what you tried and explain what problem you saw trying to use it

Answer (score 2):

It's not an `enum`, it's a `struct` that conforms to `OptionSetType`. You can create one following this pattern:

```
struct AnimalTraits : OptionSetType {
    let rawValue: Int
    init(rawValue: Int) { self.rawValue = rawValue }

    static let LaysEggs = AnimalTraits(rawValue: 1)
    static let GivesLiveBirth = AnimalTraits(rawValue: 2)
    static let HasFur = AnimalTraits(rawValue: 4)
    static let HasScales = AnimalTraits(rawValue: 8)

    static let Mammal: AnimalTraits = [GivesLiveBirth, HasFur]
    static let Fish: AnimalTraits = [LaysEggs, HasScales]
}
```

Then you can use it like so:

```
struct Animal {
    let name: String
    let traits: AnimalTraits
}

let salmon = Animal(name: "Salmon", traits: .Fish)

salmon.traits.contains(.HasFur) //false
salmon.traits.contains(.HasScales) //true

let bizarro = Animal(name: "Fictional Animal", traits: [.LaysEggs, .GivesLiveBirth])
```